# Android AlertDialog how to disable buttons before showing?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

How to disable buttons before showing alert dialog, like it is done on Fatal dialog `"Android error: The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again"`.

I use such example:

```
  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == DIALOG) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create");
      AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      adb.setTitle("Title");
      adb.setMessage("Message");
      adb.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
      dialog = adb.create();

      dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Show");
        }
      });

      dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cancel");
        }
      });

      dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dismiss");
        }
      });
      return dialog;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    showDialog(DIALOG);
  }
```

If I enable button on dialog.setOnShowListener then users get possibility to click twice on OK button.

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: how to block second click on the ok button?

Comment: either A/ you don't care or B/ remove the listener in the first click or C/ dismiss the dialog on click ?

Comment: Do you know how is realized disable buttons before showing on Fatal dialog?

Comment: i don't understand why you need to disable buttons before the user has the chance to click on it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//...All your code to set up the buttons initially

AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();
Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
if(monsterint > playerint) 
{
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

use getButton  to enable and disable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disable it by default. and use onShowListener() as below:

```
dlg.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Enable buttons..
            }
        });
```